# How do I change the color of the icons in the top bar with Android studio?

Tags: android, android-statusbar

I want to learn how to change the color of icons such as charge indicator, wifi status bar for the android device that appears in the photo below.

Ex.  The icons in the status bar are white when you open Instagram the icons in the status bar turn black.

I want to use a white status bar, but the white status bar doesn't appear because the icons are white. I'd appreciate it if you could help me out or show me a source. Sorry for my bad English.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @İsa C. you should also include the programing langue you are using in your Tags, ex. Java, Kotlyn

Comment: I really appreciate your answers. He helped me and it worked for me.